# Python: Surrounding part of a string with other strings?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, search, string-concatenation

I have a string like this

```
the gray fox
```

and I'd like to surround the word `gray` with the strings `<b>` and `</b>`. What is the most effective (and preferred) way to do this in Python?

(Context: I am building an application with a search function and I'd like to highlight the text in the search results that match the text entered by the user)

Grateful for help and with kind regards,
Tord

Comment: `"the gray fox".replace('gray', '<b>gray</b>')`

Comment: Or generally `text.replace(searchstring, '<b>' + searchstring+ '</b>')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to do this with one word, use `str.replace`:

```
sentence = "the gray fox"
new = sentence.replace('gray', '<b>gray</b>')
print(new) # the <b>gray</b> fox
```

If you need to do this with more than one word, use `re.sub`:

```
from re import sub
sentence = "the gray fox"
new = sub('(gray)', r'<b>\1</b>', sentence)
print(new) # the <b>gray</b> fox
```

Comment: Thank you Christian, the `re.sub` method is the one that I'm looking for and it works great! Can I ask if you can recommend a place to learn about regular expressions? (I must admit that I don't fully understand your answer). I watched [a PyCon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abrcJ9MpF60) about regular expressions but it didn't cover this and I need to learn more

Comment: Sure @sunyata, thanks for asking. Of course, there is no one place that will teach you everything about regular expressions, but a great place to start is the [_Regular Expression HOWTO_](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html#regular-expression-howto) article in the Python documentation. Another nice tool for learning how to use regex is [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/). It allows you to visually see how your regex's will match your input text. Happy learing :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're asking, but string concatenation in Python is easiest done with the plus operator:

```
>>> str1 = "the "
>>> str2 = "gray"
>>> str3 = " fox"
>>> interp1 = "<b>"
>>> interp2 = "</b>"
>>> str1+interp1+str2+str3
'the <b>gray</b> fox'
```

Comment: What about the case where the OP already has a constructed string? e.g.: `"the gray fox"`? You're assuming the OP can build the string from scratch, which may not be the case.